# How to get Google Drive API to recognize changes in client id and secret?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have two google accounts - one is my personal account, the other is my developer account.

In each, I set up my console, created a project, enabled the drive api, created the client id, and downloaded the JSON files.  I created a client id for a web app and an installed app - two client ids for each project, 4 total.

No matter which JSON file I use in my code, my files get uploaded into my developer account.

I had posted a similar behavior in a separate question, and at that time, all of my files were being posted to my personal account.  This is a link to that question:
[Receive "error: redirect_uri_mismatch" bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352191/receive-error-redirect-uri-mismatch-bug)

Since that question, I had uninstalled chrome, removed any trace of my gmail accounts on my hard drive and registry, deleted the data store containing the credential cache (the refresh token), and re-ran my application.  When I did all of that, all of my files now get uploaded to my developer account, and no longer my personal account.

My application will be installed on a shared device, and so, after the user is done with the device, I want the next user to use his or her credentials so that files get uploaded to their account.  The way this seems to be behaving, all users will end up uploading to MY developer account.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: you only need one project on Google developer console.  an unlimited number of users can authenticate with the same client id.   Why are you asking users to add there own credentials?

Comment: Yes, I do only have one project - one for each account.  I really don't need the one for my personal account, I'd created it just because I was testing.  Because they are two separate accounts, I don't understand the internal connection between them.  It turns out, the work I do with different companies, I may need to create and use many projects - one for each of the many accounts I would be creating.  I'm not asking for users to authenticate - that's what's happening inside the oAuth logic.  Our device is a limited-use windows-based kiosk; users use it, then generate a file to save.

Comment: I figured it out and posted an answer in case anyone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to be sure the browser cache is always cleared.  If you are going to develop an app that will be on a computer/device that will be shared by other users, you MUST ensure that your browser cache is cleared.  This is common sense; however, this has implications when your computer is shared only by YOU.

In my case, I have two applications (two different companies) which allow me to save to my Google drive.  Because of the use of both companies, I want to keep the billing and files separate, so, when I save files using company1's product, I want to save to paid google drive account #1; but when I use the other company2's product, I want to save to a different paid google drive account #2 - all of which are shared by other people in the office.  So all of the CAD developers save CAD files to one google drive account, all of the PDF documentation writers save to the other google drive account.  Some of us write CAD apps and PDF files on the same computer.

Also, at home, my wife and I share the family computer.  We don't have separate logins - we're husband and wife, no big deal.  But she wants her files in her google drive account, I want mine in my account.  Whoever uses the application first gets to determine whose drive account the files get stored, forever - until someone clears the browser cache and re-launches the application.  Clearing passwords in the browser affects EVERYTHING we visit on the internet, and is a PITA just to satisfy one product saving to two accounts.  Okay, we'll have to start creating separate Window logins, so that we don't have this problem.  Nice.  :-(

So the request is simple: When I use product1 save to google1@gmail.com drive, I provide credentials each time (or they are remembered); when I save files from product2 to save to google2@gmail.com drive, I provide credentials each time (or they are remembered).

There are two authentication stores: 
c:\users...\roaming\product1.datastore
and
c:\users...\roaming\product2.datastore

Both cache my credentials, so why this is such a problem I don't know.

Anyway, the resolution is to clear the cache.  Not happy, but that's how to get around it.